# understanding dafny code termination using binary search as an example

Tags: dafny

There is a few things I do not understand here:

1. ```
        0 <= i < a.Length && !(low <= i < high) ==> a[i] != key
   ```

In this line, why do we have !(low <= i < high)? What does this even mean? Why would the variable i be out of range of low and high?

2. why do we set `low := mid + 1;` ? I understand it is because the loop may not terminate (based on what dafny tells me), but can someone give me an example of this? where does it occur and how?

```
predicate sorted(a: array<int>)
   reads a
{
   forall j, k :: 0 <= j < k < a.Length ==> a[j] <= a[k]
}

method BinarySearch(a: array<int>, key: int) returns (index: int)
   requires sorted(a)
   ensures 0 <= index ==> index < a.Length && a[index] == key
   ensures index < 0 ==> forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] != key
{
  
  var low, high := 0, a.Length;
   while low < high
      invariant 0 <= low <= high <= a.Length
      invariant forall i ::
         0 <= i < a.Length && !(low <= i < high) ==> a[i] != key
   {
      var mid := (low + high) / 2;
      if a[mid] < key
      {
         low := mid + 1;
      }
      else if key < a[mid]
      {
         high := mid;
      }
      else
      {
         return mid;
      }
   }
   return -1;
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 What does

```
forall i :: (    (0 <= i < a.Length && !(low <= i < high))
             ==> a[i] != key )
```

mean?

It means that `key` does not occur in array `a` at certain locations.  These places are the ones where `0 <= i < a.Length` is true but `low <= i < high` is false.  Here's a picture where the array length is 12, `low` is 4 and `high` is 8.
[image]
The part shaded red is where 0 <= i < a.Length is true and the part shaded green is where `low <= i < high` is false. So this invariant is saying that `key` doesn't occur in any of the locations that are shaded both red and green.  To put it another way, it is saying that if the key is anywhere in the array, it is in the part that is red, but not green.

2 Why is `low := mid+1` the right assignment to make when `a[mid] < key`?

Well first off, since you know that `a[mid]` is less than `key`, it can't equal `key`. Furthermore every location to the left of location `a[mid]` has a value less or equal to `a[mid]`; so the contents of those locations can't equal `key` either. Thus it is safe to colour all these locations green.  I.e. the second invariant will remain true after setting `low` to `mid+1`.  After the assignment things look like this
[image]

And you also have to think about why the first invariant will remain true.  You need to be sure that `mid < high`. You can think about why that is.

So all that says that setting `low` to `mid+1` is safe. I.e. it won't make either invariant false.  If you try replacing `low := mid+1` with `low := mid+2` to speed up the algorithm, what will happen?  The verifier will report that this is not safe because it could make one of the invariants false.

Now `low := mid` would also be safe, but the problem is that since it could already be true that `mid==low` the algorithm could just get stuck at that point. (The `mid==low` case will happen when `high==low+1`.)  So `low := mid+1` hits the sweet spot. `2` would not be safe. `0` would not ensure that the loop makes progress.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed response. makes sense